# How can I reattach the PCI device when fell off the bus with `unknown header type 7f`

Tags: nic, drivers, pci

Recently my device experience network problem from time to time.
In the end, I found one of the NIC may have some issue when using the r8169 driver and recent kernel updates: 6.0->6.2
I try to re-initiate the NIC online without reboot. However, I cannot make it to work.
Here is what I did:

1. `modprobe -r r8169`
2. `modprobe r8169`
3. `lsmod | grep r8169`
   However, the NIC cannot be detected.

lspci shows it may already disconnected from the bus:

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
        DeviceName: GLAN
        !!! Unknown header type 7f
        Kernel modules: r8169
```

Usually at this point I can bring it back with a reboot.
**However, right now I am running some long lasting job that I do not want to abort.**
Thus I would like to be able to re-initiate this PCI device online.
(anyone suggest that replace NIC or down-grade kernel, please hold your thoughts, it is not valid suggestion for my issue.)

Can anyone give me some hint about how this might be achieved or is it possible at all?

the related dmesg:

```
Sep 08 10:51:39 miniserver kernel: WARNING: CPU: 10 PID: 0 at net/sched/sch_generic.c:525 dev_watchdog+0x21f/0x230
Sep 08 10:51:39 miniserver kernel: Modules linked in: rfcomm xt_CHECKSUM nvme_fabrics nft_chain_nat xt_MASQUERADE nf_nat xfrm_user xfrm_algo cmac algif_hash algif_skc>
Sep 08 10:51:39 miniserver kernel:  typec_ucsi btintel spi_nor hid_multitouch mei_pxp mei_hdcp kvm iwlmvm typec ee1004 mtd intel_rapl_msr snd_seq_midi btmtk i915 btrf>
Sep 08 10:51:39 miniserver kernel:  asus_wmi ledtrig_audio sparse_keymap platform_profile hid_generic uas usbhid usb_storage nvidia_drm(POE) nvidia_modeset(POE) nvidi>
Sep 08 10:51:39 miniserver kernel: CPU: 10 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/10 Tainted: P           OE      6.2.0-32-generic #32~22.04.1-Ubuntu
Sep 08 10:51:39 miniserver kernel: r8169 0000:03:00.0 eno2: rtl_chipcmd_cond == 1 (loop: 100, delay: 100).
```

Several things I tried:

- `sudo bash -c 'echo "1" > /sys/bus/pci/devices/$NUMBER/reset'` throw an error, probably because the device is already unreachable.
- `sudo bash -c 'echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:03\:00.0/remove'` actually remove the device. However, `sudo bash -c 'echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/rescan'` did not bring it back.
  the dmesg: `kernel: pci 0000:03:00.0: Unable to change power state from unknown to D0, device inaccessible` 
  I also tried the pci bridge hot reset with [setpci](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/474378/77353)
  It won't cause the `Unable to change power state` error, however, the rescan cannot detect any device at all.

I do not think it is hardware issue, because I have multiple devices experience the same problem, the occurrence is also kind of rare: average 1 occurrence per 2 days. I did not experience this on a device that still running older kernels.

Comment: is this an onboard NIC or an addon card? I only ask because it's probably time to change the motherboard or the card.

Comment: I've seen video card which suddenly started "falling off the bus" on ancient PC. Had to throw away that card; after diagnostics it proved itself faulty.

Comment: I agree to both replace the fault product instead of debugging it

Comment: I think it is not because of the hardware. It has something to do with the recent kernel update. If I switch back to older kernel the problem will go away

Comment: and the problem is my process already runs for more than a 1 week, it need another week to finish. I don't want to turn it off. That is why I need a way to reattach the NIC hot. Otherwise, I would not ask this question, would I?

Comment: @wang The difference between a hardware defect and the driver playing up is actually zero. For hot-adding a NIC you could use a USB one.